# how to use shortcode in my single.php file(below posts) in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

can i ask how to make my shortcode usable when i put it into my single.php file?
I want to put a carousel slider for posts below every single post.

i use wcp-carousel" slider, and the shortcode that i need to put inside is:

```
[wcp-carousel id="37122"]
```

Please help me to activate it  so the carousel slider can work.

The plugin name is : "Responsive Posts Carousel"

I already have tried this: [thing 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857623/adding-shortcodes-in-wordpress-php-file)

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: Please share a simplified version of your single.php file with <?php echo do_shortcode('[wcp-carousel id="37122"]');?> in the spot you want it and explain what is or isn't happening.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

i used "`[wcp-carousel id="37122" order="DESC" orderby="date" count="10"]` " with :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');?>
```

=>

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wcp-carousel id="37122" order="DESC" orderby="date" count="10"]');?>
```

And it worked !